# Conditional formatting based on criteria in another cell

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have conditional formatting to format a cell red if the number in the cell is greater than the refence cell. I want to add another criteria that will undo the conditional formatting if another cell says Municipal. This is applying to all cells, not just the ones that say municipal.

How do I fix this?

```
    For x = 5 To lastRowPC
       If .Cells(x, 3) = "Municipal" Then
        With .Range(.Cells(x, 77), .Cells(x, 79)).FormatConditions(1).Font
            
            .Color = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
        
        End With
        With .Range(.Cells(x, 77), .Cells(x, 79)).FormatConditions(1).Interior
        
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = vbWhite
            .TintAndShade = 0
        
        End With
 
    End If
    Next
```

This is within a larger macro as well.

Comment: are you applying all of this within another with block?

Comment: Yes theres another with that references the sheet

Comment: Because your second `with` block doesn't have an `if`? I think you just want one.

Comment: seems to work for me, assuming you are doing columns 77 to 79

Comment: Because it is a format condition and you are altering that condition, not the cell itself. If you look in the conditional formatting menu it should be the white background black text now.

Comment: actually this seems to be changing the whole conditional format which may not be what you're looking to do

Comment: I'm looking to remove the formatting if another cell = municipal. How do I change the code to achieve this?

Comment: You need to change the conditional formatting rule to include the check for Municipal. Conditional Formatting overrides cell formatting so you can't just modify the cell.

Comment: A formula rule something like this: `="And(C5='Municipal', D5=1)"` You'll need to change the D5 and the condition it is checking to match your current rule.